# dimple.js How can I change the labels of a chart axis without changing the data?

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

Say we have the bar chart of the example http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical and I want to change the x axis label from "Months" to "Meses".
How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of changing the titleShape *after* drawing, you can also change the title directly *before* drawing.

To do so, simply assign the title property:

```
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Fruit", "Year"]);
x.title = "My New Title";
```

Answer (score 7):

After drawing you can access the title object and set it's text as follows:

```
chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Fruit", "Year"]);
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
chart.addSeries(["Volume", "Year"], dimple.plot.bar);
chart.draw();
x.titleShape.text("My New Title");
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/y3BVN/

Comment: This is out of date and not the best approach in recent versions.  @philippn has given the preferred solution above.